# What is the Bugzilla REST API URL?

Tags: api, url, rest, bugzilla

I have a Mozilla Bugzilla installed in a server in my office, I want to access the REST API https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:REST_API so that I can query Bugzilla bugs from a little project management tool I have made. The problem is I cannot for the life of me work out what the API url should be.

Say I have bugzilla installed on http://bugzilla.mydomain.com/ and I want to query for bug 35 information, I thought the url should look something like this. http://bugzilla.mydomain.com/latest/bug/35

Can explain to me what the URL should look like?
Do I need to tell the admin to config bugzilla differently so I can access the API?

Any help/hints will be greatly appreciated.

Using Bugzilla Version 4.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "latest" is just part of the way the REST_API team is choosing to deploy the various versions.

You have to install the REST_API at it's own endpoint e.g. http://bugzilla-api.mydomain.com/ and configure it to use your Bugzilla. See the INSTALL file that comes with REST_API.